# Perl script rootkit (exploit)

Tags: rootkits

I received a spam abuse few days ago on my server.
As a precaution, I blocked the SMTP port and started an investigation.
I found a running Perl process. The script it was using was deleted but I found its contents in `/proc/PID/fd/3`. Here's its md5:

```
server:~# md5sum spam_scipt
c97b6d65fe2e928f190ca4a8cf23747c  spam_scipt
```

That Perl script was used to send spam from my server. It uses a domain generation algorithm to generate a URL for a dropzone where the status of the spam process is sent. I modified the script in order to see what link is being generated at the moment:

```
server:~# perl spam_scipt 
wget version is 11
Set browser wget
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
Runned postfix found, use /usr/sbin/sendmail
Probe host redacted.info
Go https://ibkxluxisp.redacted.info:1905//b/index.php?id=5cb885d577c7bbacdae44dd9f7f86b641ad60d58b1b9df07b97953a70376ec47&check=1
Generate host ibkxluxisp.redacted.info:1905
https://ibkxluxisp.redacted.info:1905//b/index.php?id=5fb58ad575c14b08785ae5255ffbf83c9f561d18e961b2eb96dc5a058a41&version=18&sent=0&user=584e6388c671f38756eac21cec
```

And the second try:

```
server:~# perl spam_scipt 
wget version is 11
Set browser wget
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
Runned postfix found, use /usr/sbin/sendmail
Probe host redacted.info
Go https://wodhvqubux.redacted.info:1905//b/index.php?id=5cb186d575c44b1e5174c7c111636063b338bc3ef4d46e4533036eded038a7&check=1
Generate host wodhvqubux.redacted.info:1905
https://wodhvqubux.redacted.info:1905//b/index.php?id=5a497fe86dde12da162b6460bb8cd215966679ad7bf97338b9b6c2e741fe&version=18&sent=0&user=544c648ace7ff7834db9fadf36bdserver:~# ;
```

The subdomain only changes now. So after a simple ping we get the IP address of the dropzone:

```
server:~# ping vodhvqubux.redacted.info
PING vodhvqubux.redacted.info (94.23.208.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns207415.ovh.net (94.23.208.20): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=4.02 ms
^C
--- vodhvqubux.redacted.info ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.026/4.026/4.026/0.000 ms
```

THose criminals have already appeared in public with the same IP address:
http://forum.spamcop.net/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t12096.html
http://www.jaguarpc.com/forums/general-hosting-network-support/26972-could-need-some-help-compromised-system-cannot-find-door.html

I do not understand how do the upload script using root access without even knowing the password. Here is the environment for that perl process:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=xx.xx.xx.xx.xx 60480 220
USER=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/tmp
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 60480 xx.xx.xx.xx 220
_=/usr/bin/nohup
OLDPWD=/root
```

Maybe that helps. I have upgraded all the software, rebooted server, but that happened again. Also there are no logs for ssh login in `access.log`.

Perl script http://www.sendspace.com/file/xfrqtt

**Can anyone assist with the abuse onto IP from OVH DC?** The criminal`s website works just perfect.

Comment: Please see [“My server's been hacked EMERGENCY” on Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/218005/1006) which includes several in-depth answers on what to do.

Answer (score 7):

Your server is *infected*. It shall be *cleansed*. With *fire*.

The primary function of a rootkit is to install itself in an inconspicuous place, and intercept whatever it needs to resist reboots and upgrades. For instance, it may have added its code in the kernel itself, and hijack read and write system calls so that it automatically reinfects the kernel file should it be upgraded.

So the path to your salvation is a complete reinstall of the system from scratch; rebuild partitions, format hard disks, fire up the OS installation CD/DVD. [It's the only way to be sure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q).

<sub>(Actually it is conceivable, and has been demonstrated in lab conditions, for some rootkits to install in the motherboard firmware, or the firmware of some peripherals, including keyboards -- as long as such firmware can be reflashed from software, it is theoretically vulnerable. It is rather improbable that your server has been compromised to that depth, so chances are that a complete reinstall will be enough -- no need to escalate to an *actual* funeral pyre.)</sub>

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea because machine could be infected once more. I think it`s kind off hole in openssh. I have found that script on other servers that have another os, kernel and are not related.

Comment: @OlierSaari - Your server itself is likely the security hole, its unlikely to be openssh, before some other localized piece of software variable.  Start by doing what Tom suggested, if it happens again, eliminate the possible reasons until it stops happening.

Comment: ...and this time do disable root ssh access and run fail2ban.

Comment: How fa2ilban would help? It uses auth.log where there no prints of login attempts.

Comment: And the main problem is that the same thing appears on different servers that are not related at all. Some of them are even "clean".

Comment: From what Olier has posted this doesn't look particularly like a "rootkit", more like a "root exploit". A fire-cleansing certainly can't hurt, but it's probable that it can be removed without totally nuking everything.

Comment: I do no know how to call it a rootkit or a exploit - my bad. 
If that would help i can upload script. But it is nothing special in it - the only useful information is the IP of the server where all logs about spam are uploaded and which gives commands to the server via HTTP reply. I abused it, but still working ..

Comment: @OlierSaari: an _exploit_ is a programming bug which a bad guy can abuse in order to make something nominally forbidden, e.g. running arbitrary code on your server. A _rootkit_ is a set of tools which a bad guy can use to turn a temporary hack (i.e. the result of an exploit) into a permanently open door for him. Usually, the first thing that an attacker does after using successfully an exploit, is to run a rootkit. If your offending Perl script survives reboots, then a rootkit was probably used. Nuking removes the rootkit (and everything else). Patching/upgrading removes exploitable holes.

Comment: Looks like i have both. Criminals use something to upload that script into /tmp directory with the file name equals to spcae - " " and then start it using system('cd /tmp; nohup perl " " &'); sleep 5; `rm -f "/tmp/ " /tmp/nohup.out`

Answer (score 3):

As Tom said, you have a rootkit.  Your system is compromised, you have to start over again from scratch with known safe files.  You can't trust any system utilities, you can't trust your logs -- if all your logs look good now; that doesn't mean they didn't log something interesting when they were attempting to break into your system (but then covered their tracks).  I'd boot to a live cd, make a read-only backup of data (not executables/not scripts) or security related files (e.g., /etc/passwd or ssh-keys), and reformat and reinstall your OS.

I sincerely doubt it was a flaw in openssh (if it was this wouldn't be happening on just your servers, but millions of servers worldwide).  This is most likely some security flaw unique to your servers.

Maybe you (or one of your users) are reusing passwords and someone intercepted a password that way.  Maybe some user has a weak password that can be brute forced (e.g., in common password dictionary lists; or is something basic like a dictionary word and a number), or you gave an account to a malicious user.  Maybe someone doesn't have a strong passphrase protecting their ssh private keys and someone got a copy.  So change all passphrases and accepted authorized public keys.

Or maybe you installed a malicious application/script or one with major security holes.

Install proactive security measures such as fail2ban (frequent failed login attempts will be slowed down/blocked) / SELinux or AppArmor (access control giving users minimum permissions) / tripwire or OSSEC  (integrity check files), etc to reduce the risk of further attacks or at least quickly notify you when you are attacked.

Comment: I do not understand why it` not a ssh problem. When i move ssh to another port - perl process stops to appear. Also if setup honeypot ssh on  22 port in the logs i see just regular brute from time to time but no successful login attempts. If i move ssh back - i see "perl" running again. If i keep it on 22 port but block connections by ip - no "perl". I do not have explanations.
fail2ban is installed. SSH has "AllowUsers root" and only few RSA keys. I have removed them, installed the only mine one-the same story. If i have a rootkit it shouldn`t matter to criminal if i move ssh to another port

Comment: @OlierSaari - Have you reinstalled your OS?  I doubt it was a flaw in OpenSSH that let them initially break into your systems.  One of the first things they did once they did get into your system is install a rootkit that replaces safe utilities like OpenSSH's sshd with a compromised version, e.g., that always accepts a malicious key (e.g., compiled into the binary).  This compromised version is based on OpenSSH (so it won't seem to be acting differently); so when you switch ports `sshd_config` the port does change (and apparently their scripts aren't scanning for other ports).

Comment: @OlierSaari - Boot off of a live cd (that you know to be safe) mount the hard disk to `/mnt/unsafe_harddrive/` and try running md5sum on the executables of various utilities (e.g., `md5sum /mnt/unsafe_harddrive/usr/sbin/sshd`) and compare the values to the original values from the operating system (and also check that the version is the same).  E.g., ubuntu 11.10 (oneric) has `OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1` with a md5sum of `6ea7510e7be723b31af0d586815b6a76  /usr/sbin/sshd`.  A program like tripwire can do these rootkit checks automatically.  Also don't trust md5sum on your corrupted system.